# Is a destructor in cpp called automatically? And are non dynamic variables removed even when the destructor doesn't mention them?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory-leaks

Given the following code, would I have a memory leak?

```
class B {
    int x;
}

class A {
    int x;
    int y;
    B* tab[10];
    A(int x, int y){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            tab[i] = new B;
        }            
    }
    ~A(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            delete tab[i];
        }
    }
int main(){
    A a(10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

In my understanding there won't be a memory leak coming from pointers to class B, but I'm afraid that I'm causing some unexpected leaks by overwriting default destructor behavior, can't there be a memory leaking coming from int x and int y since my destructor omits them completely?

Comment: You have an issue outside of what you posted in `main`.  If `main` did this `{  A a(10,10); A a2 = a; }` -- *then* you would have a problem due to the destructor deleting the same pointers twice.

Comment: I understand, I would have to write a copying constructor, however in a project that I'm dealing with object of class A is only created once so it's a non issue.

Comment: *t I'm dealing with object of class A is only created once* -- The compiler can make copies without your knowledge that copies are created.  Unless you explicitly turned off the copying using `= delete` or making copy / assignement `private`, you can't guarantee that only one copy is made.

Comment: **Always** follow the rule of 3/5/0

Comment: So if a compiler created an object of class A without my knowledge it would delete all my pointers to B objects in tab when it deletes that copy during runtime?

Comment: @Pleasebegentle -- Yes, your pointer values will be deleted when A goes out of scope.  When B goes out of scope, the destructor will delete those pointer values that were already deleted.  Thus a double-deletion error.  Object copies can occur with passing-by-value, returning by value, sometimes in other obscure places, and if object copying isn't turned off, the user could create something like `std::vector<A>`, and that is a disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my understanding there won't be a memory leak coming from pointers to class B

You are correct here.

> but I'm afraid that I'm causing some unexpected leaks by overwriting default destructor behavior

You shouldn't be afraid. Default destructors don't handle pointers well. Your implementation is good.

> can't there be a memory leaking coming from int x and int y since my destructor omits them completely?

Memory leak from a primitive? No, `int` cannot leak. `int*` can, but not a plain, good, old `int`. Same for other non-pointer types. Things thar are not `new`ed, `malloc`ed etc. don't leak and don't need coresponding `delete` or `free`s

Answer (score 0):

There will not be memory leaks since you didn't use `new` operator which would dynamically allocate memory. Instead it will use stack, and at the end of `main` function it will destruct you object.

Comment: I did use new inside A's constructor.

Comment: in `main` you did not use `new` operator to insatiate A class, and that matters, since you are putting on stack instance of `A` class. And since A  has destructor, it will clean up all instances `B` class when program execution is about to exit `main` function